# What is a quick way to find the number of lines in a piece of copied text?

Tags: text-editing

I'm not sure if this is the right forum for asking this question. But here it is. 
Suppose I copy some text from a webpage -

```
Arsenal F.C.    London
Aston Villa F.C.    Birmingham
Chelsea F.C.    London
Everton F.C.    Liverpool
Fulham F.C.     London
Liverpool F.C.  Liverpool
Manchester City F.C.    Manchester
Manchester United F.C.  Manchester
Newcastle United F.C.   Newcastle upon Tyne
Norwich City F.C.   Norwich
Hull City A.F.C.    Kingston upon Hull
Crystal Palace F.C.     London
Southampton F.C.    Southampton
Stoke City F.C.     Stoke-on-Trent
Sunderland A.F.C.   Sunderland
Swansea City A.F.C.     Swansea,  Wales
Tottenham Hotspur F.C.  London
West Bromwich Albion F.C.   West Bromwich
West Ham United F.C.    London
Cardiff City F.C.   Cardiff
```

How can I quickly find the number of lines in the text?

Answer (score 3):

Fastest way I could think of:

<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> → type *Notepad* → <kbd>Enter</kbd> → <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>

[image]

Comment: Note that the status bar is visible only when word wrap is off.

Comment: Can you please also update your answer to use vim for Unix based machines?

Answer (score 1):

supposing you are running some *nix

```
wc -l <file>
```

the `wc` program is "word count", the l parameter makes it count lines in the given file.

On Windows, probably the best is open the file in some editor and look into the status bar. Also, Word has some command for counting words, spaces, paragraphs, ...

Comment: Yes, I had thought of this, but for this I have to first save it to a file, which consumes time.

Comment: You don't need cat: `wc -l <file>`

Comment: @CodeBlue: No you don't. Run wc -l ; Paste the text ; hit ctrl+d ; read the last number.

Comment: Thanks! Why don't you make this an answer? I think it's the best one.

Answer (score 1):

On a Unix based machine, I think the fastest way is to pipe the clipboard contents to the `wc` command. On Ubuntu, the clipboard contents can be access through `xclip`.

`xclip -o` gives the following output

```
$ xclip -o
Arsenal F.C.    London
Aston Villa F.C.    Birmingham
Chelsea F.C.    London
Everton F.C.    Liverpool
Fulham F.C.     London
Liverpool F.C.  Liverpool
Manchester City F.C.    Manchester
Manchester United F.C.  Manchester
Newcastle United F.C.   Newcastle upon Tyne
Norwich City F.C.   Norwich
Hull City A.F.C.    Kingston upon Hull
Crystal Palace F.C.     London
Southampton F.C.    Southampton
Stoke City F.C.     Stoke-on-Trent
Sunderland A.F.C.   Sunderland
Swansea City A.F.C.     Swansea,  Wales
Tottenham Hotspur F.C.  London
West Bromwich Albion F.C.   West Bromwich
West Ham United F.C.    London
Cardiff City F.C.   Cardiff
```

So, all you need to do is -

```
$ xclip -o | wc -l
19
```

However, there is one caveat, the number of lines may be 1 less than the actual number of lines you can "see" if there is no "\n" at the end.

Answer (score 0):

As you do not state any specific text editor, you can use [pastebin](http://pastebin.com)

for example: http://pastebin.com/zJdZ4GEz

or you can use notepad++ which is a very nice text editor

Comment: Yes, I had thought of this, but for this I have to first save it to a file, which consumes time.

Comment: if you copy a text (I guess) you need to paste it to somewhere to see the line numbers unless you use a specific program that shows you the number of lines of the copied text. if you use text editor like notepad++ you don't have to save it which you will save <1 second.

Comment: Oh! I'm sorry, my comment was meant for another post!

Comment: Using a web application for something as simple as counting lines is completely overkill.

Comment: Ya, I agree with Marco.

Comment: Well, it depends on the web application.. if there is a web application (google shows a lot of them) would not be overkill as their purpose is to perform that specific process. OP asked the easiest way, which I believe web application would be the quickest as the OP is already using a web browser in his case, running another application would be slower as the OP considers waste of a time to save a copied text into somewhere. If I needed to count the lines, I would use a text editor.